# How can I drag edit form properly in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

When I drag a edit form, the position of the form is not valid.
Always it starts from position `(0,0)` to the window.
Its position is not relative to mouse cursor position.

How can I fix this?

These are my code.

`<table id="jqGrid"></table>
<div id="jqGridPager"></div>`

---

```
   $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: url,
        mtype: "GET",
        postData: data,
        datatype: "jsonp",
        colModel: [            
            { label: 'd_id', name: 'd_id', width: 15, key: true, hidden: true},
            { label: 'driver', name: 'd_name', width: 30, align:"center", editable: true, editoptions: {size: 40} },
            { label: 'phone', name: 'd_phone', width: 30, align:"center", editable: true, editoptions: {size: 40} },
            { label: '', name: '' }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        autowidth: true,
        height: '100%',
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 25,
        rowNum: 20,
        editurl: g_base_url + 'driver/edit',
        pager: "#jqGridPager",
        loadError : function(xhr,st,err) {

        },
        loadComplete: function () {
        },
        onCellSelect: function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {

        }
    });
```

and my jqgrid version is 4.8, jquery version is jquery-1.11.2 and jquery-ui version is 1.11.4.

please visit jqgrid demo and click edit button ("+" symbol in the page bar) and drag edit form `serveral times`. You can find its position always starts at pos `(0,0)`.

demo link is http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/edit_template/index.html

Comment: A little bit of code addition will make your problem more understandable..

Comment: It's very important to know **which version of jqGrid you use**. You should post the code or the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem. At least the option of form editing are really required.

Comment: I added jqgrid version and my codes.